# Can I run Ubuntu Studio on a server or must I only run Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, ubuntu-studio

I would like to purchase a legacy server with 8 to 16 cores and use it as a workstation. Can I run Ubuntu Studio on a server or must I only run Ubuntu server? Will the speed of say video editing be enhanced by a system?

Answer (score 2):

A server is just a computer. As Free Software, there are no legal restrictions on where you can install a given distribution of Ubuntu. Given that the major difference between Ubuntu Server and Desktop is not the kernel but just the set of applications installed, you should have no trouble running Ubuntu on compatible server hardware.

Multiple CPU cores will only speed up software that is optimized to utilise multiple cores, so it depends on the software you will be running, but you will be able to run multiple applications simultaneously with less slowdown at the least.

For video editing, a combination of fast discs and processor power is probably the desired combination - but I'm no expert on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you can install a graphics card (or if it has onboard graphics) you can use is as a desktop machine.

Video *editing* will probably be sped up  by a multi-core machine though video encoding (what you'll do after editing) will probably not. Encoding is still a relatively single-threaded task so faster cores, not more cores are more useful.